# Can we create a reference to DOM objects like document.location

Tags: javascript, dom

As we have a wonderful concept called hooking where we can create a reference to a function and connect another function In the same way can we create a reference to DOM objects. For example can we create a function and **hook** it to **document.location** so that whenever document.location is used the other function must be triggered.

Comment: I understand that certain properties in the DOM don't act like typical objects in javascript, for example `window.location.href`.  Assigning that property to a value triggers the event to change pages, though I'm not sure if it's an overrideable feature in javascript or if it's somehow treated differently by the browser.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this. Setting document.location to anything will immediately trigger a redirect to whatever string representation the value has.